# Creating your own diacritics

Tags: accents

How does one create one's own diacritics? To give a concrete example, I want to be able to typeset something that looks like

## ä

but has three dots above the letter. I'm looking for an answer that looks comparably nice to existing diacritics, if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option is to use the [`accents`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/accents) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

$\dddot{\mathbf{a}}\quad\ddddot{\mathbf{a}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In `amsmath` this is already defined: `\dddot{a}`. You can even have 4 dots: `\ddddot{a}`. (Works in math mode only though.)